# Which action in Logic Apps to use to Transfer Files from SFTP to Blob in Azure

Tags: azure, blob, sftp, azure-logic-apps

Hi I have been trying to transfer files from SFTP to Blob and vice versa using Logic Apps,
which Action should I use to transfer files from SFTP to Blob and from Blob to SFTP.

Thank you.

I do not know which action I should use and I have been struggling to find answers as well online.

Comment: With all due respect, it could t be any clearer in LigicApps. There’s an SFTP connector and a Blob Storage connector. Get the content of the file via the SFTP connector and then upload it to storage via the Blob connector. There’s no single operation, if you want that, use ADF.

Comment: yes but I cannot pick the right action to use for that. can I have more specific action to use because there's more than one action for SFTP and action in Blob that can be chosen. I am just new in Azure Logic Apps and was trying to research more on this. thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> Transfer files from SFTP to Blob

I do agree with @Skin, You can use below **`design`** to do this:

You can use SFTP connector in only Standard Plan of Logic app:

[image]

Then use Create blob in Azure Blob storage connector:

[image]

Then:

[image]

> Transfer files from Blob to SFTP

To obtain the above use below design(Here done using SFTP-SSH Connector an alternative way):

In consumption plan you cannot use SFTP connector:

[image]